# Convert the property value to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a property in the following way to keep datetime information

`public string ExecutionTime{ get; set; }`

ExecutionTime value is set as `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`
How can i change the property value to appear as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt` and show in a **textbox**.

Comment: Is there a reason your property is of type `string` and not `DateTime`?

Comment: I do see a valid point in you. but it was already set and it is used in many other files

Comment: I have to ask: why would you not store it as a `DateTime` ? But: there are two obvious ways to approach this: parse as a `DateTime` and then write it to a different format, or: just apply a basic string re-mapping against different character posisitons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your date is stored as `string` :

1. Parse the string to get the actual `DateTime`
2. Convert back to `string` with different format

You'll need [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
// Your date
string inputDate = "20-01-2012 02:25:50 AM";

// Converts to dateTime
// Do note that the InvariantCulture is used, as I've specified
// AM as the "tt" part of the date in the above example
DateTime theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Now get the string to be displayed
// I've also specified the Invariant (US) culture, you might want something else
string yourString = theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But you really should store a date as `DateTime`, not `string`.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a `string` property. Instead i would store it as `DateTime` since it actually seems to be one. You can format it howsoever you want *when you display it*.

```
public DateTime ExecutionTime{ get; set; }
```

for example:

```
Textbox1.Text = ExecutionTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Otherwise you always need to parse that string to a `DateTime` and vice-versa and you might even run into localization issues (in future).

Comment: Remember that the meaning of the colon `:` in the format string depends on the current culture's `TimeSeparator`. If for example the culture is `"bn-IN"` (Bengali in India), it will write `05.13` instead of `05:13`. If that is not desired, either escape the colon in the format string, or use the invariant culture.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime d;
var isValid = DateTime.TryParse(ExecutionTime, out d);
if (isValid)
{
    textBox1.Text = d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```